# Access member of class instance from outside its definition

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids

I have this type:

```
newtype Mem s a = Mem { runMem :: s -> (a,s) }
```

and I have to create an instance of monoid for this type, but to do so I have to use the mempty and the mappend of the monoid a, regardless of what it may be. How would one go about doing that?

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Mem s a) where
    mempty =  --runMem with the mempty of a
    f@(Mem aa) `mappend` g@(Mem aaa) = --runMem with mappend of a
    f@(Mem s) `mappend` mempty = f
    mempty `mappend` g@(Mem ss) = g
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just use `mempty` and `mappend` and the type system will figure out which `mempty` you meant.

Comment: For example `mempty = Mem (\s -> (mempty, s))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mempty` is simply the `mempty` of `a` and the `s` that was passed in.

```hs
mempty = Mem (\s -> (mempty, s))
```

`mappend` can be defined as running `f`, then `g` based on the results of `f`, then mappending the results:

```hs
f `mappend` g = Mem (\s -> 
                    let (fa, fs) = runMem f s
                        (ga, gs) = runMem g fs
                    in (fa `mappend` ga, gs))
```